# Android PdfDocument damaged when saved to external storage

Tags: java, android, xml, pdf, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm trying to create a simple PDF document using Androids native PdfDocument class (from api 19). What i want is to have an XML layout file, for example called *pdf_doc.xml*, and then inflate it when creating the PDF. Inside the *pdf_doc.xml* i would then have a bunch of views that could be fetched in the code, and then drawn onto the PdfDocuments pages, seperately. The problem is, that this creates a damaged PDF file.

On the other hand, if i just create a simple TextView, in my *main_activity.xml* (the xml of the activity i'm using when creating the PDF) and use that TextView instead, it works fine.

Why does it make a difference whether the TextView comes from an inflated layout or the activity's layout? Am i trying to do this the wrong way?

FYI: It also fails when creating the TextView programmatically.

Below is my source code. These two functions are called right after eachother. The first one creates the PDF, the other one saves it. The problem is in the view, called *content*, that im getting from the inflated layout. If i instead put that TextView in the Activity's XML and then get it from the activity, like this    `act.findViewById(R.id.pdf_text);` it then workst as intended.

Code:

```
    public static PdfDocument createPdf(Activity act){
        PrintAttributes printAttrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
                setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR).
                setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4).
                setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).
                build();

        ViewGroup mainLayout = (ViewGroup) View.inflate(act, R.layout.pdf_doc, null);

        int pageHeight = printAttrs.getMediaSize().getHeightMils() / 1000 * 72;
        int pageWidth = printAttrs.getMediaSize().getWidthMils() / 1000 * 72;

        PdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(act, printAttrs);
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

        View content = mainLayout.findViewById(R.id.pdf_text);
        content.draw(page.getCanvas());
        document.finishPage(page);

        return document;
    }

    public static void saveFile(PdfDocument doc){
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/pdf_test");
        myDir.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(myDir, "test.pdf");

        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            doc.writeTo(out);
            doc.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Log.d("pdftest", "path: " + path);
    }
```

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Maybe i wasnt clear enough, but im not tring to draw the whole layout at once. I'm simply taking a TextView FROM the layout and trying to draw that. I cannot see the difference in doing that, compared to taking it from the layout the activity is using...

Comment: No not at all. As i said, if i take a TextView from the activity's XML, i can draw that onto the PdfDocument pages canvas, but i cannot do it with a TextView from a programmatically inflated layout ?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Since your `mainLayout` will have zero height and zero width (you haven't inflated it into a parent), try manually laying it out, by calling `measure()` and `layout()` on it, in that order. You will need to specify a size in pixels that you want the layout to be sized to.
2. Call `out.getFd().sync()` after `out.flush()` and before `out.close()`. I doubt that this is causing your specific problem here, but it's a good idea and is unlikely to hurt.

Comment: Thank you for two constructive suggestions. I will try it out tomorrow morning !

Comment: What would the parameters be for measure() if i wanted the layout to just fill as much space as possible? AT_MOST?

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann: Beats me. I haven't tried that. I'm not sure that there is "as much space as possible", since there is no parent. Since IIRC you have to provide paper sizes in pixels, use the same number of pixels (or perhaps a bit less) for this, perhaps.